# How to fix the Stored xss error in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, stored-xss

Here is my requirement. in my visual force page i'm getting stored xss error in escape="false".

```
<apex:outputText value="{!wrk.html_description__c}" escape="false"> </apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Is html_description__c a text field, or rich text field?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using  tag with attribute “escape = false” then please make sure either 
The value being printed is some fixed non user inputted text like

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!"<!DOCTYPE html>"}"/>
```

Else, value is being escaped via Apex etc using Security Coding Library escape functions or any other equivalent. For ex.

```
String usertext = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('usertext');
// the next line encodes the usertext similar to the VisualForce HTMLENCODE function but within an Apex class.
usertext = ESAPI.encoder().SFDC_HTMLENCODE(usertext);
```